# What will be faster: fetch documents with $lookup of fetch them concurrently?

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongodb-query

Suppose we have two collections: `parents` and `children` and they have 1 to many relationship (example with Node.js MongoDB client).

```
const parents = client.db('my_db').collection('parents');
const children = client.db('my_db').collection('children');
```

The first approach would be:

```
await parents.aggregate([
    {$match: {_id: parentId}},
    {$lookup: {
        from: 'children',
        foreignField: 'parentId',
        localField: '_id',
        as: 'children'
    }}  
])
```

The second approach would be:

```
await Promise.all([
    parents.findOne({_id: parentId}),
    children.find({parentId})
])
```

So I am wondering if there is any difference between approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the fields that are used for `$lookup` or `find` are properly indexed, both approaches should be similarly performant. But for first approach, if the `$lookup` may results in many of `children` document matched, you may hit the 16MB document size limit. Check out [this pipeline optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#-lookup----unwind-coalescence) for more details.